# Assigning the right type to generic type variable of a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, express, typing, typescript-types

I am trying to type the function called `route`. I use it in my express project

```typescript
const morph = (params: Function[]) => (req: Request) => params.map(f => f(req))


const applyTransformers = (transformers: Function[]) => (response: any) => {
    for (const transformer in transformers) {
        response = transformer(response)
    }
    return response
}

export const route = <
  H extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>,
  T extends any[] = Parameters<H>,
  P extends Function[] = { [K in keyof T]: (req?: Request) => T[K] }
>(handler: H, params: P = [] as P, transformers: Function[] = []): RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler => (
    wrap(
      async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
        // debugger

        const result = await handler(
          ...morph(params)(req)
        )

        res.send(applyTransformers(transformers)(result))
      }
    )
  )

// Usage: 
// id = (req: Request): string => req.params.id
// customParam = (param: string) => (req: Request): string => req.params[param]
// ... 
// app.get('/example-route/:id/blah/:blah', route(handler, [id, customParam('blah')])
//                                        handler: (string, string) => Promise<any>
```

The problem is as follows:
I don't want to provide generic types to the route function when using it. I want it to understand that types of the `handler` and `params` "match" and if they don't "match" I would like to get a TypeError. But it doesn't work as expected. For example if `handler` is of type `(string, number) => Promise<any>` and `params` is of type `[(Request) => number, (Request) => string]` TypeScript will not give me an error.

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] which clearly displays your issue and does not exhibit unrelated problems to distract from the issue.  Right now if I paste that into my own IDEs I see a bunch of errors about undeclared values and types, as well as at least one genuine problem having to do with calling a string as a function.  I suggest that you put your code into a standalone IDE and fix/remove any problem you're not asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I did some refactoring to the original code but the solution to this concrete example would be making generic type P extend the type that it is being assigned. That is replacing

```
P extends Function[] = { [K in keyof T]: (req?: Request) => T[K] }
```

with

```
P extends { [K in keyof T]: (req?: Request) => T[K] } = { [K in keyof T]: (req?: Request) => T[K] }
```

so that the code would look like:

```
export const route = <
  H extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>,
  T extends any[] = Parameters<H>,
  P extends { [K in keyof T]: (req?: Request) => T[K] } = { [K in keyof T]: (req?: Request) => T[K] }
>(handler: H, params: P = [] as P, transformers: Function[] = []): RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler => (
    wrap(
      async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
        // debugger

        const result = await handler(
          ...morph(params)(req)
        )

        res.send(applyTransformers(transformers)(result))
      }
    )
  )
```